# Android login authentication to remote MySQL database

Tags: java, android

Here's my java code:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    ArrayList < NameValuePair > postParameters = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", txtUsername.getText().toString()));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", txtPassword.getText().toString()));

    //String valid = "1";  
    String response = null;
    try {
      response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://www.sampleweb.com/imba.php", postParameters);
      String res = response.toString();
      // res = res.trim();  
      res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
      //error.setText(res);  
      if (res.equals("1")) {
        txtError.setText("Correct Username or Password");
        //Intent i = new Intent(CDroidMonitoringActivity.this, MenuClass.class);
        //startActivity(i);
      } else {
        txtError.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      txtUsername.setText(e.toString());
    }
  }
});
```

I thinks there's an error in my res.equals because it keeps saying "Invalid Username or password" even though I've entered the correct username or password. But when I change the res.equals to res.contains it keeps saying "correct username or password" even though i've entered the correct username and password. I really need your help. to all mastered in android development. Hope you could help me on this. And also, when i change the txtError.setText(res) just to check if it returns 1 and 0 it does not.

Comment: Post PhP Code the problem might be there(by the way I'm using same code and I'm stuck in same problem haha:)

Comment: Have you tried `trim()`? `txtUsername.getText().toString().trim()`

Comment: what is that???never heard of trim()

Comment: if you try loading http://www.sampleweb.com/imba.php in a browser looks like the website does not exists.

Comment: @TheRedFox I'd say that page is just a bogus.

Comment: so?what you mean by that?

Comment: here is mine but i got completely same problem it just kept saying either right password or wrong http://54.149.195.28/chat_server/authentication.php

Comment: If i try sending a request with a tool like CocoaRestClient i can see the page genaretes an error 500, so i guess the error is on the server

Comment: Sorry the answer above was for @BiggDawgg

Comment: you see i get the response defiantly with echo but fearing if and else statement...i think problem in java code how to handle my code is completely the same as heres and again if i switch for example if(res.equals"1"//for correct) i will always get correct result even if i type wrong credentials,so how to handle it i don't know

Comment: fail passing password with http

Comment: I don't think it will ever work because you are executing the network call in the main thread and then updating the view.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be done in the php file not in the Android code:

```
<?php

define('DB_USER', "root"); //username used to connect to the database.
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); //password used to connect to the database.
define('DB_DATABASE', "dbname"); //database name
define('DB_SERVER', "127.0.0.1"); //database server address

?>
```

Using a JSON parser, you would then need to parse the data on the server. You need to use something similar to the following:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    //Method to connect to the database
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        //The following works just as in normal GET and POST methods
        try {
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

In a second class, you would then need to define the connection parameters as follows:

```
public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String loginURL = "http://www.sampleweb.com/login.php";
    private static String registerURL = "http://www.sampleweb.com/register.php";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

In addition to this, you would finally need to use your application classes to parse data and show it to the users. There are several online tutorials on how this can be done.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @ching Could you please accept this answer and upvote it this has helped you? :)

Answer (score 1):

It is really difficult to figure out what is going on with out the response from server. To debug the issue, for both valid and invalid user name/password combinations check the response of  http://www.sampleweb.com/imba.php using a POST library like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)